# How can I fix this “Please select...” error?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

[image]

Someone who can help me with this error when I want to install Sql Server Data tool

Comment: Choose a SQL Server instance, just like the message tells you.

Comment: OK THANK GRAHAM

Answer (score 0):

Do you need install a SQL Server Instance [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and then, select your instance